# synchronizing vim-terminal pwd and vim pwd

Tags: terminal

I'm looking for a way to synchronize the vim-terminal pwd and vim pwd.
so for example

```
in normal terminal, navigate to directory a
>cd /a/

open vim terminal
> vim -c ":term ++curwin"

inside vim terminal navigate to directory /b/
>cd /b/
```

Now the vim pwd is /a/ and the vim terminal pwd is /b/.

is there a way to make it so that the vim-terminal cd will affect the vim pwd?

I found :h 'autoshelldir' but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: so you already found `'autoshelldir'`, that is an option, you are supposed to *set* it, like `:set autoshelldir`. Note, this may depend on the terminal you are using

Comment: setting it didn't work, and the :h said that it requires some setup but the explanation went above my head

Comment: then I would say your terminal does not support it :(

Comment: Is there a way to know which terminal will support it?

Comment: I don't know. From the documetation, it looks like VTE related terminals should support it. Or maybe you need to configure your terminal to support OSC7 properly.